# Reading CSV file's 2D array values as a 2D array and not string

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

Hi I am using pandas to read a csv file in python. My csv file has two columns. The first is an integer and the second is a 2D array (30*30). I need to use these matrices in the second column to calculate something else. However it gets read as a string. How can I read it as a 2D array? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Welcome Netz, please consider sharing your code and an input sample of your CSV.

Comment: The CSV looks like this @leun4m.     2,"[[ 8.41822503e-02  8.17640282e-02  5.17258043e-02 -2.39597383e-02
   1.18681165e-01 -9.36849101e-02  1.97876259e-02  4.94846392e-02
   1.24758030e-01 -1.24689228e-01 -1.40542789e-01  4.40931465e-02
   9.78649466e-02  1.05642643e-01 -2.03528190e-03  1.05246857e-01
  -8.65420242e-02 -7.44484171e-02 -6.72294718e-02  6.68634466e-02
  -1.21631100e-01 -1.05583891e-01 -9.91376448e-02 -2.82331718e-02
  -2.398..